Why ChebNets are K-Localized?
I am reading about spectral graph convolutions and I reached the point where ChebNets defined the filters on graphs as a Chebyshev polynomial instead of a convolution. I am trying to understand this Lamma and its proof which is the basis of why Chebyshev Polynomials will be K-Localized. Can someone explain the proof to me? The reference of this Lamma is text
enter image description here
In the above proof I can not understand how this summation is written and what is its meaning:
enter image description here
